# Firestore dynamic compund query in Golang

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a `GET` collection API that will return list of firestore's document collection where the `Client side` can send dynamic queries, like this

```
type Condition struct {
  Field    string
  Operator string
  Value    interface{}
}

// Client side 
conditions := []*Condition{
    {Field: "email", Operator: "==", Value:"some@email"},
    {Field: "fullname", Operator: "==", Value: "somename"},
}

docs := Get("user", conditions)
// do something with docs    


// Server side
func Get(cn string, conditions []*Condition) *firestore.DocumentIterator {
  collection := firestoreClient.Collection(cn)

  for _, v := range conditions {
    collection.Where(v.Field, v.Operator, v.Value)
  }

  return collection.Documents(ctx)
}
```

This return no errors, however instead of returning documents with matching conditions, it will just return everything in the collection, of course i can just do something like

```
....
cn := "user"
collection := client.Collection(cn)
collection.
  Where("email", "==", "some@email").
  Where("fullname", "==", "somename").
  //chain some other Where condition
```

I have searched everywhere, but the solution provided is by manually chaining the `Where` method like above, which is not ideal since the `Client side` will control the queries. And i don't feel like creating a function for every possible query combinations, i also don't think that that would the best approach

How can i achieve this in Golang Firestore?

**UPDATE**

The accepted answer is working, however it doesn't check if the client didn't send any `where conditions`, it will trigger a `null pointer error`. So i added some checks just incase anyone is stumbling upon the same problem

```
type FirestoreConditions struct {
    Field    string
    Operator string
    Value    interface{}
}

// conditions []*FirestoreConditions

var q firestore.Query
if len(conditions) > 0 {
    for i, v := range conditions {
        if i == 0 {
            q = collection.Where(v.Field, v.Operator, v.Value)
            continue
        }
        q = q.Where(v.Field, v.Operator, v.Value)
    }
    q = q.OrderBy(query.OrderBy, sort).Limit(int(query.Limit)).Offset(int(query.Offset))
} else {
    q = collection.OrderBy(query.OrderBy, sort).Limit(int(query.Limit)).Offset(int(query.Offset))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the variable type for return value. Create the query from collection for the first data in array then appends for the next data

```
var q firestore.Query

for i, v := range conditions {
    if i == 0 {
        q = collection.Where(v.Field, v.Operator, v.Value)
    } else {
        q = q.Where(v.Field, v.Operator, v.Value)
    }
}
```

get the results by referring to that query

```
iter := q.Documents(ctx)
```

Answer (score 0):

modify the loop to this

```
for _, v := range conditions {
    collection = collection.Where(v.Field, v.Operator, v.Value)
}
```

Comment: this will throw an error `cannot use collection.Where(v.Field, v.Operator, v.Value) (value of type firestore.Query) as *firestore.CollectionRef value in assignment`